# Equation with seven unknowns

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ be positive integers greater than or equal to $2$. What values of these numbers satisfy the equations $$a+b+c+d+e+f+g  =18 \tag 1$$
$$a(b+c+d+e+f+g+3) + b(c+d+e+f+g+3) + c(d+e+f+g+3) + d(e+f+g+3) + e(f+g+3) + f(g+3) + 3g = 188 \tag 2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equation (2) is just $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} ab + 3\sum_{sym} a = 188$.  Using (1) we then get $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} ab = 134$.

Now squaring (1) and subtracting twice the above we get $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} a^2 = 56$.

Now, at least $3$ of the variables are $2$, because otherwise their sum is greater than $18$.  Suppose $e,f,g$ are $2$, then we get $a+b+c+d = 12$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 44$.

Now $4\cdot 3^2 < 44$, so we must have another variable equal to $2$ (say $d$).  Hence we get $a+b+c = 10$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 40$.  $(a,b,c) = (3,3,4)$ still has $a^2+b^2+c^2$ too small, so another variable must be $2$, say $c$.  So we get $a+b=8$, $a^2+b^2 = 36$. $4^2+4^2$ is too small, as is $3^2 + 5^2$, while $2^2 + 6^2$ is too big.

Thus there are no solutions.

Comment: Sorry to anyone confused by all the edits.  I did a "sanity check" on the last one and made a mistake on my sanity check and thought that I had a mistake in the above.

Comment: What is "sym" under the sum?

Comment: It means "symmetric".  That is, I want the appropriate symmetric polynomial with one of its terms equal to the given term: in the case of $\sum_{\text{sym}} a$ that's just $a+b+c+d+e+f+g$; in the case $\sum_{\text{sym}} ab$ I want to sum over all (unordered) pairs, getting $ab+ac+\cdots + fg$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Now at least 3 of the variables are 2,because otherwise their sum is greater than 18."?

Comment: All the variables are at least 2; the sum of seven 2s is 14.  If five or more of them were at least 3, then the sum of all of them would be at least 14+5 = 19.

Comment: I still don't understand your sums. What do you mean by "sum over all (unordered) pairs"?

Comment: There we go, coin down! Thanks a lot people, this is a nice site.

Comment: @Parseval,consider the set {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}The ordered pairs are {a,b},{b,a},{a,c},{c,a}. . .Here,{$a,b$} is not equal to{$b,a$}.However,unordered pair means that order does not matter i.e. {a,b}={b,a}.So. when he says 'sum over all unordered pairs',he means that he wants to add together ab,ac,ad,ae. . .i.e. the product of the unordered pairs. 
 
 delete

Comment: I think I'm missing something. When you do the "squaring (1) and subtracting the above", how can you get $\sum a^2 = 134$. Doesn't make sense since if you actually square one and subtract twice the above it will be $$\sum a^2 - 2\sum ab = 18^2 - 268 = 56 \Leftrightarrow \sum a^2 = 56 + 268 = 324 \neq 56$$

Comment: @Parseval,(sum of squares of numbers) is not the same as  (sum of numbers)^(2)

Comment: So how then does he get 56? I'm really sorry for being so slow but I don't really follow that solution, can you present a solution that's not so "read between the lines" sort? Obviously he means (sum of numbers)^2 since that's the only way you'd get 56.

Comment: And I still can't grasp how $$ eq(2) = \sum_{sym}ab+3\sum_{sym}a=188$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} ab$ is just $a(b+c+d+e+f+g)+b(c+d+e+f+g)+c(d+e+f+g)+d(e+f+g)+e(f+g)+fg$.Note that this is just equation(2) with $3a+3b+3c+3d+3e+3f+3g$ missing.But $3a+3b+3c+3d+3e+3f+3g$ is just $3\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} a$. To get equation (2),we need to add this to $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} ab$. That is why $\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} ab$$+$$3\displaystyle \sum_{\text{sym}} a$ is equal to equation (2).